# Add directives using another directive in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

My problem is that i would like to create a single directive called date-input that can be applied to a html input field.

Within this custom date-input, i then want to add other directives from other modules to the same input.  For example, i am using textMask found here https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2

I do not want to apply custom masks all over my application, but instead would like to add my own directive, apply that to all my inputs, and if something needs changing, i only have to change my 1 directive, rather then all the places i have implemented this code.

Using textMask I currently have to do all this for a number field, let alone unmask the value upon setting my ngModel.  I do not want to copy this code throughout my site on all components, these thought a simple directive would be great.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
       [(ngModel)]="inputValue" [textMask]="{mask: mask, guide: false}" />
```

**MY TYPESCRIPT**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask.js';

export class NumberComponent {
    mask = createNumberMask({
                    prefix: '',
                    suffix: '',
                    decimalLimit: 0
                });
    inputValue: string = '';

    unmask(val) {
        let value = val.replace(/\D+/g, '');

        if (value == '') {
            return null;
        } else {
            return +value;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to create a simple directive called "number-input" that will add the [textMask]="{mask: mask, guide: false}" to an input at runtime.

Can this be done?